# How to set up twilio taskrouter outbound call?

Tags: php, twilio, twilio-api, outbound

I am trying to set up outgoing calls through Twilio task router. I am creating tasks through PHP with the all the necessary attributes (instruction, to , from, post_work_activity_sid ) but the created task doesn't set up a call between the twilio client and the external phone number. I was hoping that tasks created by the program would create a conference call between worker(browser) and external client. I keep getting an error that is shown below. I have a assignment php on my application server which de-queues calls to my workers (Browser clients). Currently, incoming calls from external number to browser clients through task router is working as expected. However, outbound calls generates a task and a reservation is assigned but Twilio is not able to dequeue the call to a worker.
Is there a way to create a task for voice call such that the task is created using Twiml Enqueue verb? Or is there a better way of handling outbound calls using the Twilio taskrouter so that calls are assigned successfully to the workers using Browser client ?

As per this thread: [Can outbound calls be made through Twilio TaskRouter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42609952/can-outbound-calls-be-made-through-twilio-taskrouter), I tried using instruction call.I have also gone through the documentation and another stack overflow post about assignment callback URL but it's not clear and am not sure what I could be potentially doing wrong.

Error message:
The dequeue instruction can only be issued on a task that was created using the  TwiML verb

```
<?php
require_once('TwilioVendor/autoload.php'); // Loads the library
use Twilio\Rest\Client;
$sid    = "ACxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
$token  = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
try{
$twilio = new Client($sid, $token);
$task = $twilio->taskrouter->v1- 
>workspaces("WSxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")->tasks- 
>create(array("attributes" => json_encode(array(
//"instruction"=>"accept",
//"instruction"=>"conference",
"instruction"=>"call",
"to"=> "client:Bob",
"from"=> "+61123456789",
"post_work_activity_sid"=> "WAxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
)),
"workflowSid" => "WWxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
)
);
}catch(Exception $e)
{
echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
print($task->sid);

**Assignment Callback code**   

<?php
$assignment_instruction = [
'instruction' => 'call','to'=> 'client:Bob',
'from' => '+61xxxxx','url'=>'CRM REST END POINT'
];

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($assignment_instruction);

**CRM REST END POINT TWIML**
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
require_once 'TwilioVendor/autoload.php'; 
use Twilio\Twiml;
$reservationSid= $_REQUEST['rsid']
header('Content-Type: text/xml');
?>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Response>
<Say voice="woman">You will now be connected to the customer</Say>
<Dial>
<Queue reservationSid="<?$reservationSid?>"/>
</Dial>
</Response>
```

Comment: Are you using the TaskRouter JS for your agent view? Or do you have an assignment callback URL set up?

Comment: @philnash I have an assignment callback URL. I am able to create a task  using below code and my  callback URL queues the call to my browser client. However, the part that I am missing is how to bridge this browser call to the external number?  

$twilioClient = new Client($sid, $token);
$task = $twilioClient->taskrouter->v1->workspaces("WSbxxxxxxx")
                               ->tasks
                               ->create(array(....
Call Back URL
<?php
$assignment_instruction = [
  'instruction' => 'call','to'=> 'client:Bob',
 'from' => 'xxTwilioNumberxx','url'=>'https://'
];

Comment: Could you edit your question and include the code you are using to respond to your Assignment callback webhook, please?

Comment: @philnash I have updated the code in the original question now. Looking forward to your comments, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

TaskRouter will only generate calls to your workers when a task is created by the [`<Enqueue>` TwiML](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/enqueue) verb. Creating a task with the REST API, even if you add call attributes, will not generate a call when you use the `dequeue` or `call` instruction.

Instead, you will need to manage the task and call yourself. When your worker is sent the reservation and accepts it, you should [use the REST API to create the call](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/make-calls), connect it to your browser client and then dial out to the end user.

Comment: Many Thanks!! The solution worked. Although, it's a bit cumbersome to manage all the aspects of reservation, call and wrapping up calls in the code, everything works smoothly.

Comment: @susmitkoirala Can you please share your email with me? I may need to hire you. Please approach me on skype umair.hamid91

Comment: Hi @Umair Hamid you can reach out to me on susmit.koirala@gmail.com